Как закруглить углы внутрь с tailwind next.js
Вот параметры границы в элементе fieldset, используется вместо div, чтобы добавить legend.


<fieldset className="overflow-y-auto p-4 mx-auto w-[307.57px] 
h-[376.81px] left-[41.68px] top-[732.34px] 
bg-[#FFFFFF] border border-solid border-[#7DADCD]  
border-opacity-[0.4] text-[#50636A]">



как правильно описать псевдоэлементы, чтобы края границы были скруглены внутрь?


Очень сомневаюсь, что tailwind вам тут как-то поможет. Вот нативный css, попробуйте под себя адаптировать - https://codepen.io/aliencash/pen/VWOxMB?editors=1100
